# Xfce broked / network not working

Tags: networking, terminal, apt, kali-linux, xfce

Well. Some days ago i made an 'apt-get install virtualbox' on my kali linux 2.0.

I use `xfce`. `apt-get` downloaded like 300mb of files and installed about 1gb. Everything ok. Then i restarted my computer. Everything broke.

My graphical login disappeared, got a terminal login (very strange), so i discovered i could login using `startx`, i did it, but i got a surprise, everything was VERY UGLY, like i was using windows 3.1, icons pixeled, etc...

Wherever... System kept running `xfce`, programs working, etc... Tried to run internet, got disconnected, very strange too. So i searched the network manager to see my connections, where? The menu was gone.

Tried many aproaches:

NetworkManager

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager force-reload  
service network-manager start  
ifconfig wlan0 up  
dhclient wlan0  
lspci  
ip link show eth0  
ip link set eth0 up  
airmon-ng check kill  
service NetworkManager start
```

None of them worked.
Its three problems in one:

Terminal login
ugly Xfce
Broked internet

The main problem is the internet, because without internet i cannot even repair the other problems and i cannot work.

Thought in undo the apt-get, don't know how, how can i recover everything? Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Merry Xmas. Kali is not meant as a desktop environment, it is meant to be run in a VM by experienced Linux administrators that also are IT security specialists, so these things happen, It looks like installing VirtualBox uninstalled some parts of your system. You could try `sudo apt-get install task-xfce-desktop xfce4-goodies` but I would backup, format and install Mint, Devuan, Debian or Ubuntu instead.

Comment: How can i run apt-get install task-xfce-desktop, without internet?

Comment: Also, virtualbox should work in Kali, as virtualbox is necessary to many security applications

Comment: Easiest solution: restore from a recent backup, or just reinstall completely. You shouldn't have anything important saved on a Kali Linux system anyway

Comment: Also, when debugging your networking, pick one method and stick with it. Using all of those network tools will conflict with each other and get you nowhere. If your graphical environment is broken, ditch Network Manager and use `ifconfig`, `ip addr`, or the standard Debian `/etc/network/interfaces` with the `ifup/ifdown` scripts. But just one of those will suffice.

Comment: "How can i run apt-get install task-xfce-desktop, without internet?" I guess you should not be running Kali, then, if you do not know how to setup your network (I do not mean to come over as some ****, but this is just the start of your troubles with Linux, Kali will be a pain no end and I really want you to enjoy Linux). If you really want to run Kali, start off with an easier distro first like the ones I mentioned and read a book on Linux Administration, seriously, Kali is for veteran admins, only!

Comment: I should not do this, but, to help us help you, we would need information about your network. If you have another system on the network, please provide the output of `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (Linux) or `ipconfig /all` (Windows). What IP address did your Kali have before or, if you don't remember, what IP address is NOT in use on your network ? Add that to your question, then we can fix the network.